# Flexible css layout with header, footer and scrolling body inside container

Tags: html, css

There is a block with header, body and footer parts inside of it. Header and footer heights are fixed, body height is determined by its content. I need the outer block size to be the size of its contents but not more then the size of its container. If the body height exceeds maximum possible size, then the `y-scroll` is shown for body, but header and footer stay at the top and bottom of outer block.

I made the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vL8mmezu/). But I could only get as far as when I resize window the scroll appears for outer block, not for body block only.

This is CSS and HTML:

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.innerContainer {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.header, .footer {
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
}

.body {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='innerContainer'>
    <div class='header'></div>
    <div class='body'>text<br>text<br>...</div>
    <div class='footer'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do what I need without using JavaScript?

**EDIT: I made an image to make it clear what I need.**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found is using CSS3 calc. Doesn't work in Android browswer, though... [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vL8mmezu/3/)

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header, .footer {
    height: 30px;
    background: blue;
}

.body {
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
}

.bodyContainer {
    max-height: calc(100% - 60px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
        <div class='header'></div>
        <div class='bodyContainer'>
            <div class='body'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='footer'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Well Here is your code from what I understand that you want the header
>   sticks to top and footer in the bottom and you can scroll the body if
>   necessary in the container size.

```
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='innerContainer'>
        <div class='header'></div>
        <div class='body'>text<br>texttext<br>texttext<br>texttext<br>texttext<br>texttext<br>texttext<br>texttext<br>texttext<br>texttext<br>text
</div>
        <div class='footer'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

We need to style the footer and header separately plus your style as you will see in the code below
So you add to **.innerContainer** (`position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;`) and for the **.body** you add(`height: 50%; overflow-y: auto;`)

```
   body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.innerContainer {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.header, .footer {
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
}

.body {
  background: green;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 36%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

**I hope that what you want and if you have any question please let me know.**

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I need. The footer must be on the bottom of the innerContainer, so if the body height is less then the screen size, it should stick to the bottom of the body, and not to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: which body you mean the class or the tag?

Comment: The tag. The behavour I need is exactly as the fiddle I linked, but when you resize the window, the scroll should appear not for the whole container, but for the .body div container, and the footer should remain visible.

Comment: ok so should be as I did but the footer flow in the bottom with body div, right?

Comment: Yes, and the .body div should not overflow with header and footer.

Comment: About the width you can erase (right & left) of .innerContainer or play with it as you want.

Comment: In the solution you offer the height of the .body div does not depend on its content, but I need it to be so. And the footer goes below the border at little size.

Comment: can you please explain it more, Also can you clear your browser and try it on different browser?

Comment: I understand that and I did as in image, but I don't know what do you mean by "the height of the .body div does not depend on its content, but I need it to be so. And the footer goes below the border at little size" ?

Comment: You set the .body height as 50%. So no metter how long the content of the body is its height will always be 50% of innerContainer, which is in your case 100% of outer container. I need body to be just one line if there is only 1 line of text (and footer right after that line), 10 lines if there is 10 lines of text, and 100 scrollabale lines if the content is long (but in this case footer must be on the bottom of innerContainer).

Comment: Ok, this is as you want but the problem is in IE it will be 11 lines instead 10.
You can play with it little bit.
for small device you will need to set another style @Media Queries. for perfection.
I hope my code is helpful to you.